# Recording military medals in Gramps

Tags: military-records, gramps

Military medals are considered to be important genealogy sources. What is the best way to record them in Gramps?

Answer (score 14):

I've been using a `Military Service` event with a description along the lines of `Award of the XXX to YYY` and an appropriate date and source.